# Ubuntu上でOpenSSLのalpnの関数を使う方法

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

この[**リンク先**](https://github.com/0xfffffff7/HelloHttp2ssl/blob/master/hellohttp2.cpp)のコードをコンパイルしようとすると,下記のようなエラーが出てコンパイル出来ません。Opensslのバージョンが1.0.2以上じゃないとalpnが使えないというのは、調べた結果わかったので、[**この方法**](https://sandilands.info/sgordon/upgrade-latest-version-openssl-on-ubuntu)で1.0.2dにあげたのですがダメでした。
どなたか解決方法知っている方がいましたら教えて下さい。
ubuntuのバージョンは、14.04.3です。

```
root@ubuntu:~$ g++ -g -Wall -I/usr/local/include -lssl -lcrypto -lstdc++ -o hellohttp2.o hellohttp2.cpp
hellohttp2.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
hellohttp2.cpp:133:49: error: ‘SSL_set_alpn_protos’ was not declared in this scope
SSL_set_alpn_protos(_ssl, protos, protos_len);
                                            ^
hellohttp2.cpp:146:54: error: ‘SSL_get0_alpn_selected’ was not declared in this scope
SSL_get0_alpn_selected(_ssl, &ret_alpn, &alpn_len);
                                                 ^
```

Comment: 何度かやり直して成功した理由は、断定は出来ませんがVMwareの簡易インストールが原因のようでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 15.04 で openssl 1.0.2d を /usr/local 以下にインストールした後で、以下を実行しました。

```
$ g++ -g -O2 -Wall -I/usr/local/include -o hellohttp2 hellohttp2.cpp -lstdc++ -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -ldl
```

これで `hellohttp2` が作成されます。

おそらく、`-o hellohttp2 hellohttp2.cpp` をライブラリのリンク指定(`-ssl -lcrypto -dl`)よりも前に置く必要があります。

Comment: Ubuntu14.04で無理だったので15.04入れてやってみましたが無理でしたね。ちなみに、openssl 1.0.2dをどのようにビルドしましたか？

Comment: openssl 1.0.2d のソースコードアーカイブを展開して、`./config --prefix=/usr/local; make; sudo make install` としました。また、`hellohttp2` を実行すると HTML ファイルが出力されます。

Comment: 同じ手順でビルドしてみましたがダメでした。argusさんは、ビルドするとopenssl versionとした結果が1.0.2dに変わりましたか？

Comment: はい、`OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015` と表示されます。libssl.a や libcrypto.a は /usr/local/lib/ にありますよね？

Comment: 再度、最初からやり直してみたらOpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015となりましたが、libssl.aやlibcrypto.aがありませんでした。後、謎なのがエラーが
hellohttp2.cpp:95:9: warning: variable ‘error’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int error = 0;

に変わりました。

Comment: `hellohttp2.cpp:95:9: warning: variable ‘error’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable] int error = 0;`でexeファイル出来てなかったのですが、何度か最初から試したらwarningは消えてませんが、exeファイルが出来るようになり、いちよ問題は解決しました。